# How do you remove an entire directory except for certain subdirectories in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, rm

Suppose I run the following command in linux:

```
$ mkdir -p mp3 jpeg/dir1 jpeg/dir2 txt
$ touch mp3/1.mp3 mp3/2.mp3 mp3/3.mp3
$ touch jpeg/1.jpeg jpeg/2.jpeg jpeg/3.jpeg
$ touch txt/1.txt txt/2.txt txt/3.txt
```

This will create a directory structure like:

```
├── jpeg
│   ├── 1.jpeg
│   ├── 2.jpeg
│   └── 3.jpeg
│   └── dir1
│   └── dir2
├── mp3
│   ├── 1.mp3
│   ├── 2.mp3
│   └── 3.mp3
└── txt
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 3.txt
```

How do I invoke the linux "rm" command to remove everything in the "jpeg" directory except for "dir2" subdirectory?

So I'm looking for a command that looks something like:

```
rm -rf -not dir2 jpeg
```

But when I run that command on Centos 7, I get the following error message:

```
rm: invalid option -- 'n'
```

My target output directory structure should look like:

```
├── jpeg
│   
│   
│   
│   
│   └── dir2
├── mp3
│   ├── 1.mp3
│   ├── 2.mp3
│   └── 3.mp3
└── txt
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 3.txt
```

Would appreciate all/any help from the linux scripting community

Comment: `rm` has no option like that. You need to use `find` to remove everything except the one you want to keep.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: If you enable `extglob` (`shopt -s extglob`), then `rm -rf jpeg/!(dir2)`

Comment: Wrong dupe marked as that other question is for `android`. On OSX that other answer gives this error: `usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `find` command to delete everything in `jpeg` directory except `dir2`:

```
find jpeg -mindepth 1 -path 'jpeg/dir2' -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: You need a wildcard `jpeg/dir2*`. Otherwise it will delete the files inside `dir2`, but not `dir2` itself.

Comment: Or one could use `-prune` to stop recursion at that point and not even read the directory's contents; cheaper than reading them and then filtering them out.

Comment: Thanks Barmar and @CharlesDuffy `-prune` should have been there, fixed

Comment: @anubhava - your command worked, although I am getting a message stating "find : cannot delete 'jpeg' : directory not empty". is there any way to suppress this message?

Comment: Try: `find jpeg -mindepth 1 -not -path 'jpeg/dir2' -prune -delete`

Comment: With `find` version `4.8.0` i get: `find: The -delete action automatically turns on -depth, but -prune does nothing when -depth is in effect.  If you want to carry on anyway, just explicitly use the -depth option.` and using `-depth` removes files inside `jpeg/dir2` again.

Comment: @anubhava `find jpeg -mindepth 1 -path 'jpeg/dir2' -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} +` seems to work, can you confirm the problem, and maybe update the answer?

Comment: @anubhava Unfortunately, I can not vote to reopen, if they don't want `bash` questions on SO, why do they have this tag? Ridiculous...